# LDAP Query for OU's

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Sorry for being an uber pain people, its all very new :(

Already had alot of help on this, but don't seem to be able to see the problem, I am trying to populate a combo box with a list of all the current OU's, later to send each machine within that OU a shutdown command. (Acquiring AD OU list & Active Directory list OU's) were my previous Q's.

```
        string defaultNamingContext;
        //TODO 0 - Acquire and display the available OU's
        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
        defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
        DirectoryEntry entryToQuery = new DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext);
        MessageBox.Show(entryToQuery.Path.ToString());

        DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entryToQuery.Path);
        ouSearch.Filter = "(objectCatergory=organizationalUnit)";
        ouSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

        SearchResultCollection allOUS = ouSearch.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult oneResult in allOUS)
        {
            //comboBox1.Items.Add(oneResult.ToString());
            comboBox1.Items.Add(oneResult.Properties["name"][0]);
        }
```

I have been through and debugged everything i know, the searcher isn't picking up any results, hence why nothing is populated in the combo box.

Comment: I have just tried to add the whole LDAP path in manually 
entryToQuery = "LDAP://OU=G-T-P,DC=G-T-P,DC=LOCAL"

I know that there are definately department OU's under here in the tree, I have replaced the property to load to ["distinguishedName"] to see if maybe it could pull that back, though thinking about it that will make no difference. Super stumped at this point!!!

Comment: +1 Interesting question for AD related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have had to use the non indexed
>   objectClass rather than Catergory.

You just need to spell it correctly: **objectCategory** - not objectCate**r**gory

(you have an "r" too much in there..... :-)

Comment: I knew i should have gone to school more often :P

Answer (score 2):

Works :) :)

I have had to use the non indexed objectClass rather than Catergory.

The combo box has populated perfectly fine now.

EDIT:
{
"(objectClass=organizationalUnit)"
}

Comment: +1 For finding the answer to your question all by yourself, and to provide it to the others who could be searching for such either. While using the DirectorySearcher class, always provide the "objectClass" property in your DirectorySearcher.Filter property member.

Comment: Thanks Will 

Why is it that objectCatergory doesn't work, anyone know?